# Solve $t\, e^t=t+2$ for $t>0$.

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

I need to solve the following equation:
$$t\, e^t=t+2\, ,$$
for $t>0$. Do I need to use Lambert W function, or there is some other method?

Thanks!

> PS. I know that any equation of the form $A+Bt+C\log(D+Et)=0$ has solutions which, if they exist, can be expressed using Lambert function. But I do not think that $t\, e^t=t+2$ can be rewrite in this way... am I wrong?

Comment: Numerical methods I guess. You are correct (to me) when you say that you cannot rewrite as $A+Bt+C\log(D+Et)=0$. For $t>0$, I bet that Newton method will converge in very few iterations using $x_0=1$.

Comment: you can also use a numerical method, eg Newton-Raphson method

Comment: WolframAlpha does not give an answer using Lambert's function so I'm guessing this cannot be solve that way.

Comment: @T.Gunn. WolframAlpha is not the $\alpha$ and $\omega$ in mathematics. I am "almost" sure that there is a solution in terms of the generalized Lambert function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in a comment, there is a solution involving the generalized Lambert function. If you look [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf),  C. B. Corcino and R. B. Corcino  proved
that in the asymptotic expression of the  generalized Bell numbers
one needs to solve the equation $$x\,e^x + r x=n$$ which is exactly your case. The remaining of the paper addresses the more general case of $$e^{-cx}=a \frac{ \prod_{i=1}^n (x-t_i)} {\prod_{i=1}^m (x-s_i) }$$

Loooking at the posted equation, from a purely numerical point of view, Newton method will converge quite fast using $t_0=1$ observed by inspection. The successive iterates would be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1.000000000 \\
 1 & 1.063499184 \\
 2 & 1.060100663 \\
 3 & 1.060090320
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

We also could use $[1,n]$ Padé approximants built around $t=1$ and get explicit approximations of the solution. For example
$$t_{(1)}=1+\frac{2 (3-e) (2 e-1)}{2+e+5 e^2}\approx 1.0599978$$
$$t_{(2)}=1+\frac{3 (3-e) \left(2+e+5 e^2\right)}{2 \left(-3+9 e+15 e^2+8 e^3\right)}\approx 1.0600921$$
$$t_{(3)}=1+\frac{8 (3-e) \left(-3+9 e+15 e^2+8 e^3\right)}{24-21 e+291 e^2+265 e^3+65 e^4}\approx 1.0600903$$

Comment: The paper has defined an inverse function of $x e^x+r x$ called $W_r(x)$ to solve this equation. As the op's question, the answer is $t=W_{-1}(2)$

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that this can be solved using the Lambert $W$ function. When one attempts to put it in the form that you specified, one ends up with
$$\ln\bigg(\frac{t}{t+2}\bigg)+t=0$$
If we let $\frac{t}{t+2}=u$, then we have
$$\ln(u)+\frac{2u}{1-u}=0$$
$$(1-u)\ln(u)+2u=0$$
So if you can find some way of solving equations in the form
$$A+Bt+(C+Dt)\ln(E+Ft)=0$$
then this would be possible... however, I am afraid that you may have to attack this problem without the Lambert $W$.

If you would like to approximate, I would recommend using iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you rearrange the original expression to get:
$$t=t \exp(t)-2$$
it is easy to see that the solution is a **fixed point** for function $f(t)=t \exp(t)-2$, that is a contraction map in the region $t\in (-\infty, 0)$. Therefore a solution can be found by the sequence $$t_{i+1}=f(t_i),\ \ i=0,1,2,...$$
that is guaranteed to converge to a fixed point if we start with $t_0$ in the interval in which $f(t)$ is a contraction map. Doing that will lead to $t^*\approx -2.238643$ after a few iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plot:

[image: Plot]

The solutions to
$$t{e^t} = t + 2$$
are
$$t \approx -2.23865$$
and
$$t \approx 1.06009.$$

**Credits:** I used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+t(e%5Et)+%3D+t+%2B+2+for+t).